# Equivalent of Unix find command on Windows

Tags: windows, linux, find

What is the equivalent of the Unix [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command on Windows?

I see that the `find.exe` on Windows is more like a `grep`. I am especially interested in the equivalent of

```
find . -name [filename]
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
dir <drive: [drive:]> /s | findstr /i <pattern>
```

- alternative -

```
dir /s <drive:>\<pattern>
```

#### example

```
dir c: d: /s | findstr /i example.txt
```

- alternative -

```
dir /s c:\example.txt
```

Comment: `dir c: /s example.txt` works, too.

Comment: @DevSolar can you recheck your command? I've tested it on Windows 5.1 Build 2600 SP3, and your command just gives me the list of files in the directory c:

Comment: Uh... sorry. Serves me right to type from memory. `dir /s C:\example.txt` it is.

Comment: for the most similar results I use `\b` for brief (output only paths); `find <folder> -name <pattern>` -> `dir /s /b <folder><pattern>`. E.g. `find /tmp -name *.txt` -> `dir \s \b C:\temp\*.txt`. However `dir` always returns a list of absolute paths, whereas `find` always gives paths prefixed with `<folder>`

Comment: adding `\B` to `\S` allows to have a more terse output, with 1 file per line with full path,, no headers, no size info, etc...

Answer (score 40):

With no additional cmdlets installed, you can simply use `Get-ChildItem`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.zip -Recurse $pwd
```

Comment: In which case you probably want to use one of the short aliases `dir`, `ls` or `gci`, unless you are writing a script.

Answer (score 28):

The `Find-ChildItem` Cmdlet in Windows Powershell is an equivalent of Unix/Linux find command

http://windows-powershell-scripts.blogspot.in/2009/08/unix-linux-find-equivalent-in.html

**Some of Find-ChildItem Options**

1. `Find-ChildItem -Type f -Name ".*.exe"`
2. `Find-ChildItem -Type f -Name "\.c$" -Exec "Get-Content {} | Measure-Object -Line -Character -Word"`
3. `Find-ChildItem -Type f -Empty`
4. `Find-ChildItem -Type f -Empty -OutObject`
5. `Find-ChildItem -Type f -Empty -Delete`
6. `Find-ChildItem -Type f -Size +9M -Delete`
7. `Find-ChildItem -Type d`
8. `Find-ChildItem -Type f -Size +50m -WTime +5 -MaxDepth 1 -Delete`

Disclosure: I am the developer of `Find-ChildItem` cmdlet

Comment: Thank you.  This is definitely more in mind of what I'd be looking for in answering this question.

Comment: **`Find-ChildItem` is not an official cmdlet and it is not included in PowerShell; you have to download this cmdlet from some guy's OneDrive**. There's no difference between that and just downloading bash, cygwin, unixutils or any other program that just lets you run UNIX's `find`.

Comment: @jagadish-g A bloody shame it's not already been integrated to PS long time ago. Did you try to file a PR in the powershell github repo.

Comment: ...and link is dead.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Unix's find to search for files in a directory hierarchy, then 
the Powershell way is to use `Get-ChildItem` (alias is `gci`) cmdlet and filter the results with the `Where-Object` (alias is `where`) cmdlet.

For example, to find all files (starting from `C:\Users\` and recursively) with the word 'essential' in its name, use the following:

```
PS> gci -Path "C:\Users\"  -Recurse | where {$_.Name -like '*essential*'}
```

The `-like` option allows you to use wildcards for pattern matching.

Answer (score 3):

This one is not exactly GNU find, but more closely matches the linux command line philisophy under powershell:

```
PS> dir -recurse -ea 0 | % FullName | sls <grep_string>
```

Example:

```
PS> cd C:\
PS> dir -recurse -ea 0 | % FullName | sls "Program" | sls "Microsoft"
PS> dir -recurse -ea 0 | % FullName | sls "Program" | sls "Microsoft" | out-gridview
```

Note: Everything returned after "| % FullName" is a string, instead of an object.

You can also use the Where Operator, "?", however, its more work, and not much faster:

```
PS> cd C:\
PS> dir -Recurse -ea 0 | ? FullName -like "*Program*" 
                       | ? FullName -like "*Microsoft*" 
                       | % FullName 
                       | out-gridview
```

Here's a quick shortcut:

```
PS> function myfind {dir -recurse -ea 0 | % FullName | sls $args }

PS> cd C:\
PS> myfind "Programs" | sls "Microsoft"

#find all text files recursively from current directory
PS> myfind "\.txt$"

#find all files recursively from current directory
PS> myfind .
```

Comment: Find -exec grep {} from UnixUtils doesn't work properly it seems "no such file or directory". This solution: PowerShell.exe -Command "dir -Recurse -ea 0 | ? FullName -like '*.log' | sls error", from within a batch script works. Note: must use single quotes inside, double quotes outside.

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell you can use `Get-ChildItem` (aka `ls`), as noted in other answers.

```
ls . -Filter *.zip -Recurse
```

It might also be useful to get full paths of files instead of short names.

```
(ls -Path . -Filter *.zip -Recurse).FullName
```

And you can also easily execute arbitrary commands on the files found.

```
(ls -Path . -Filter *.zip -Recurse).FullName | ForEach-Object -Process {
    # The $_ variable is the path to a located file.
    echo "Found file: $_"
}
```

Comment: I think that's by far the best answer.`

`(ls -r).FullName`

is basically the same es a simple `find` in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls c:\ file.ext -r
```

You can use this simple powershell command.
use -ErrorAction Ignore to get rid of permission errors.

Comment: I like the simplicity. Adding `-name` makes it an even simpler listing of names only.

Answer (score 1):

While not a full substitute, this simple batch file solved most of the problem for me:

```
# findw.bat
# 
# usage: findw dir search-pattern
#
dir %1 /s /b | findstr /i %2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use get-childitem very similar to find.

```
get-childitem -recurse [startpath] -name [filetofind]
```

`[startpath]` is the path where recursion should begin (e.g. `.` for the current directory)

`[filetofind]` is what you are looking for.

It is even possible to do this from cmd (without interactieve powershell):

```
powershell -command "get-childitem -recurse [startpath] -name [filetofind]"
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), install a Linux VM like Debian or Ubuntu. Then you have the C-disk available under /mnt/c.

```
find /mnt/c/ -name [filename]
```

You can of course cd into the directory first.

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/John/Documents
find . -name [filename]
```

If I try this last search, I need quotes around the filename, while not when using the absolute path.

Comment: I thought the S of WSL stood for "Subsystem" not "Sublayer"?

Comment: @AJM - You're correct!