# How to port $(shell find . -name '*.cpp') on windows?

Tags: linux, windows, shell, find, makefile

I have this in makefile:

```
# find cpp files in subdirectories
SOURCES := $(shell find . -name '*.cpp')
```

So I wanted to make generic `FIND` command that behaves correctly on windows and linux:

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
   # WINDOWS
   RM = erase /Q
   FIND = ???
else
   # LINUX
   ifeq ($(shell uname), Linux)
      RM = rm -f
      # This is probably wrong too, but I have no idea how to do it right
      FIND = $(find . -name '$1')
   endif
endif
```

Of course, I don't even know how to make parametrized find template for linux. But more importantly, I cannot find command to find all files by pattern. Windows has this:

```
dir * /s/b | findstr \.cpp$
```

Which is beautiful, but that uses regular expression... How can I port this right, so that find behaves well on both systems? Doesn't makefile have it's own method for finding files?

Comment: Is there any reason a `dir *.cpp /s` is insufficient?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent of Unix find command on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/401495/equivalent-of-unix-find-command-on-windows)

Comment: You should look into MinGW/Cygwin. These are collections of Unix utilities that run on Windows, and let you run Unix-originated makefiles on Windows (plus you get a Linux-like shell on Windows...).

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at portable build systems, that cope with such differences from conception.