# How to move all .txt files in directory structure to another directory via command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-8.1, batch-file

I have a pretty extensive directory structure:

```
c:\foo
  \foo\1
  \foo\1\doc1
  \foo\1\doc2
  \foo\2
  \foo\2\doc1
  \foo\2\doc2
  ...
  \foo\10\docX
```

I want to move (not just copy) all files with .txt extention to a another directory `c:\textfiles`.

I'd like to do that via command line (the regular one, not Powershell), possibly in a batch file.

I've tried the `move` command but it only seems to work on files in the current directory.  I've also tried `xcopy`, but it doesn't delete files on the source after the copy is complete.

Comment: related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357233/how-to-move-all-files-with-specific-extension-from-all-subdirectories-to-their-p/13243519#13243519

Answer (score 2):

From: [How to move all files with specific extension from all subdirectories to their parent using CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13243519)

> This command will copy recursively al pdf files from source to target
>   directory using cmd in windows 7 - tested and works
>
> for /r "c:\source_directory\" %%x in (*.pdf) do move "%%x"
>   "c:\target_directory\"

See also:

[windows - Move all files from multiple subfolders into the parent folder - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/999922/move-all-files-from-multiple-subfolders-into-the-parent-folder)

[Copy Multiple Files from Subfolders to Single Folder - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/copy-multiple-files-from-subfolders-to-single/60375efe-426b-42b8-8048-30a7d94847c6)

Answer (score 1):

#### rsync

`rsync` is a tools available for [windows too](https://rsync.samba.org/download.html), normally used to remote synchronize directory... but it works fine on local directory too... as stated in its own description

> a fast, versatile, remote (**and local**) file-copying tool

From this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83596/66388) on unix.stackexchange...

```
rsync -a --prune-empty-dirs --include '*/' --include '*.txt' --exclude '*' source/ target/
```

**Note** that it exists an option to delete the files from the origin that you can include in the command line, I think the one you search for is `--remove-source-files`, but **check it carefully**. Another option you may find useful is `-n`

> ```
>     -n, --dry-run               perform a trial run with no changes made
>     --remove-source-files       sender removes synchronized files (non-dir)
> ```

#### find

`find` is another tool you can find in your `bash` shell under windows as well as a compiled executable(gnu [findutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/findutils.html))...
The following line works under Linux but you can modify the `cp` statement to be compliant with your system specifications. From another [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107647/66388)...

```
 find . -name '*.txt' -exec cp --parents \{\} /target \;
```

#### Windows equivalent of `find`

From another [quesiton/answer](https://superuser.com/questions/401495/equivalent-of-unix-find-command-on-windows) for your batch script you may use this hints...

```
 dir <drive: [drive:]> /s | findstr /i <pattern>
```

... of course if they felt the need to do a **power**shell it is reasonable to expect that in *that* environment there should be a more simple way to do it...

but maybe the following one is an enough simple starting point for your script:

```
dir c:\foo /s *.txt
```