# Powershell/Cmd: Find files with a certain extension, excluding error messages from inaccessibility

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, find

My question is **almost** answered by [this question answer](https://superuser.com/questions/401495/equivalent-of-unix-find-command-on-windows#answer-1160018), but the command suggested there spits out many error messages re: the inaccessibility of certain system folders when searching the entire system drive.

So, is there any way to make `gci -Path "C:\" -Recurse | where {$_.Name -like '*.txt'}` return all txt files on C:, ignoring inaccessible folders?

I would also accept any answer that points to an alternative cmd or powershell command that effectively does the same thing. MTIA! :-)

UPDATE: Apologies for the negative comments guys, I obviously didn't test out this **exact** scenario properly, nor did I explain what I **really** want (see Mael's comment below and my replies to it).

I am trying to automate the process of setting up an SSH client, and want to search for any/all public keys that already exist on the system before I go unnecessarily creating new ones. So the extension that I'm **actually** searching for is .pub, not .txt!

I originally said .txt coz I thought it would be clearer and easier to test, without effecting the results...obviously I was wrong! But why?? Ideally, the command that I'm searching for would work with **any** file extension (i.e. `*.ext`, **not** `*.ext*`), and not produce false positives like `<left part of file or folder name><extension><right part of name>`.

Thanks again everyone! :-)

Comment: i’m thinking this might be less of an issue of what script you are running and more to do with your file associations - what program is currently set to open public keys by default? i was under the impression that .pub in this circumstance was just a way to append the key and not technically an extension - as opposed to .pub which is the extension for Microsoft Publisher files. you may need to be running this in conjunction with `assoc` and `ftype`; i’ll try to find time to test this theory and edit my answer if it helps.

Comment: @mael' Hmm, very interesting indeed! I never would've thought that this had **anything at all** to do with file associations! I guess I'm even more of a fuzzy searching n00b than I thought! Anyway `.pub` is currently associated with Notepad on the system that I'm testing this on. Many thanks for your continued effort! :D

Comment: I've updated my answer with a slightly different approach

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell:
Short version:

```
gci C:\ *.pub -file -ea silent -recurse
```

Full version:

```
Get-ChildItem -path C:\ -filter *.pub -file -ErrorAction silentlycontinue -recurse
```

Comment: Using `-filter *.pub` should be faster as it uses the file system provider. (+1)

Comment: *.txt _is_ the filter in my example. `Path` and `Filter` are positional parameters. Will edit answer to reflect *.pub

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `for` loops for this:

```
for /r "c:\" %A in (*.txt) do (echo %A)
```

This `for /r` loop goes through `c:\` and all subfolders of `c:\`, each iteration will assign a text file to parameter `%A`, then echo `%A` in the command window, or you can make it `(echo %%A>>sometextfile.txt)` to pipe the results into a text file.

Reference: [For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

---

**Updated with Information from Comments:**
I've been unable to replicate your issue - I threw a bunch of files (Microsoft Publisher files, public keys with a .pub extension added to them, private keys, text files, etc. all with various names i.e. "no.pub.txt", "thanks ok.pub", "maybe a.pub.ppk", etc.) into a bunch of folders (also included "pub", ".pub", etc.) and ran the script and it only ever returned the files with a .pub extension - whether those were actually working .pubs or not.

From my limited understanding, public SSH keys always contain specific strings (I assume based on how they are generated, but I only have experience with PuTTy) - so let's try nesting a loop that uses `findstr`:

```
@echo off

for /r "c:\" %%A in (*.pub) do (
    for /f "delims= tokens=*" %%B in ('findstr /i /c:"BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY" "%%A"') do (
        echo %%A
    )
)

pause
```

This loops through `c:\` and pulls out everything your `for /r` returns for `*.pub` - since this is unreliable for you for some reason, we nest it with `for /f` to go through those results and pull out everything that contains the string `BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY`, after which we echo our original parameter `%%A`. Give that a shot and see if it helps - if your public keys are setup differently you can just replace the string within the quotes.

Reference: [Findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), [for /r](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html), [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)

Comment: This does not handle one of the requirement in the question ("error messages re: the inaccessibility of certain system folders when searching the entire system drive.")

Comment: Wow you guys jumped on this quicker than I've ever seen before on **any** StackExchange site! Many thanks! However, this answer does the same thing as all the others I've found on StackOverflow and SuperUser...it echoes out files with txt **in the name**, not files with an **extension** of txt. Seriously, how hard is it for this to be done on Windows without WSL?? In any Unix variant, it would literally take me 2 freaking milliseconds with the `find` command!!

Comment: OK I've re-read the above comment and taken a deep breath...apologies for the rant and for getting frustrated. And just to make sure that I'm being **really** clear about what I don't want, the suggested for loop gives me `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk\2.2.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\...` as one of the results when I use `*.pub` for the extension. What gives??

Comment: What specific environment are you using? I can't reproduce your results - I tried setting up a small folder with .txt files, .bmp files with .txt in the name, and folders with .txt in the name, and the for loop is only returning the .txt files. Are you running the command-line through specific software?

Comment: @mael' I'm running Windows 10 x64 1903 (the latest major release, only about 2 months old) and simply using cmd. For Powershell commands, I'm prepending `powershell `. Just out of curiosity, what are you running? This would help me understand why so many people think that this and other commands like it are valid solutions.

Comment: @mael' Ah ha! I just tried your test scenario myself, and it indeed works. Apologies for the negative comments everyone! I obviously wasn't specific enough with my question. Will update it to reflect what I **really** want!